# ImportError: No module named cv2.cv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, windows-10

**python 3.5 and windows 10**

I installed open cv using this command :

```
pip install opencv_python-3.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

This command in python works fine :

```
import cv2
```

But when i want to import cv2.cv :

```
import cv2.cv as cv
```

This error comes up :

```
import cv2.cv as cv
ImportError: No module named 'cv2.cv'; 'cv2' is not a package
```

So what is the problem and how can i fix it?

Comment: if I remember correctly `cv2.cv` has been removed in OpenCV 3. You just need `cv2`

Comment: so i should replace cv with cv2 in the whole code?

Comment: Yes. You may have used `cv2.cv` for old legacy functions... in this case they won't be in `cv2` and you should use the new function instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as @Miki said :

`cv2.cv` has been removed in OpenCV3 and functions have changed

And this is OpenCV3 Documention:https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Try import cv2.cv2 as cv
This worked for me to get past this error.