# How to install cv and cv2 both python packages on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I have got a python code from open source community where it imports cv as well as cv2. After installing opencv using conda 'import cv2' resolved. But still I have issue with 'import cv', where it shows 'ImportError: No module named cv'.

Few other things I have tried:
1. sudo apt-get install python-opencv
2. pip install opencv
3. import cv2.cv as cv

Can any one help me how to resolve "No module named cv"? 
Note that I am using python version 2.7.13

In my code I am using as below:

```
import cv2
import cv
```

And getting the following error:

```
    import cv
ImportError: No module named cv
```

Comment: Could you show us the import line of the code? also according to [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python) "pip install opencv-python" allow you to use "import cv2". Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048313/cannot-import-cv-on-opencv2) may help you. Edit: Also this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215102/installing-opencv-for-python-on-ubuntu-getting-importerror-no-module-named-cv2) (older) may have some information for you (they used from from cv2.cv import *).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named cv2.cv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39534496/importerror-no-module-named-cv2-cv)

Comment: @EricGodard I have added the code segment and error too. Also tried 'from cv2.cv import *' which shows the following error:
    from cv2.cv import *
ImportError: No module named cv

Comment: since version 3 `cv` was removed from `cv2`

Comment: @magicleon,  I am using opencv version 2.4.9.1, I have used the following command to get version 'pkg-config --modversion opencv'

Comment: The `cv` module has been removed in OpenCV 3+. What are you trying to use it for? You likely don't need it.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds, I am trying to access cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS

Answer (score 0):

The `cv` module was removed actually before OpenCV 3.0. Regardless, most things accessible through the `cv` module are still accessible. The `cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS` setting is now `cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS`.

Basically, the constants given by `CV_XXX_XXX` used to be accessible through the old `cv` module via `cv2.cv.CV_XXX_XXX` but now it's not necessary---just remove the prepended `CV_` and use the `cv2` module.